# 16.04 very slow boot (many minutes); runs fine once booted; blame highlights sendmail, postfix, apache2, plymouth-quit-wait.service

Tags: boot, apache2, postfix, plymouth

My machine takes a very long time to reboot.  It has always done so.  Once it's up, it runs fine.  I dug into it months ago and gave up.  I used to get [these](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51381) ATOM BIOS boot loop errors, which went away for the most part, but appear every now and then when booting.

`/var/log/boot.log` shows:

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
```

### Checks after booted

```
$ sudo ls -l /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
srw------- 1 root root 0 Apr 28 10:51 /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket


$ systemd-analyze blame
1min 30.228s sendmail.service
1min 30.228s postfix.service
1min 30.228s apache2.service
1min 20.195s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     50.239s fail2ban.service
     30.317s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
     30.084s mysql.service
     20.323s lvm2-monitor.service
     20.239s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
      1.426s docker.service
       130ms ModemManager.service
       122ms accounts-daemon.service
       114ms gpu-manager.service
       109ms grub-common.service
       102ms NetworkManager.service
        93ms thermald.service
        85ms apport.service
        85ms systemd-logind.service
        83ms systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service
        79ms irqbalance.service
        75ms apparmor.service
        72ms console-setup.service
        72ms media-maestro.mount
        69ms networking.service
        69ms speech-dispatcher.service
        69ms ondemand.service
        67ms avahi-daemon.service
        61ms lightdm.service
        46ms systemd-modules-load.service
        46ms keyboard-setup.service
        44ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        42ms systemd-journald.service
        42ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
        41ms upower.service
        41ms user@119.service
        38ms colord.service
        36ms udisks2.service
        30ms ssh.service
        30ms user@1000.service
```

`systemd-analyze plot >` [output.svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY5er.jpg)

Anyone have suggestions for things to look into?

Comment: It is hard to know but my guess is there is an underlying "problem" with networking and those services are waiting for your network to come up. Hard to know. See http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/systemd-blame.html

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, looking into your linked resource now...